# VB.Net how to wait for a different form to close before continuing on

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, winforms

I have a little log in screen that pops up if a user selects a certain item on my main form. How do I get my code to stop executing til my log in form closes?

This is what I am doing so far. Basically i want o execute the code after MyLogin closes.

```
    BMSSplash.MyLogin.Show()

    If isLoggedIn Then
        BMSSplash.MyBuddy.Show()
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
    End If
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One easy and reasonable option would be to show the form modally with `ShowDialog` instead of `Show`. This will block the rest of your application until the form is closed:

```
If BMSSplash.MyLogin.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    ' Form was closed via OK button or similar, continue normally... '
    BMSSplash.MyBuddy.Show()
Else
    ' Form was aborted via Cancel, Close, or some other way; do something '
    ' else like quitting the application... '
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `BMSSplash.MyLogin.ShowDialog()` instead to have the window shown as what is referred to as a **modal** dialog.

Answer (score 0):

To stop other code from executing you need to show the other window as a modal dialog.  This is typically done an WinForm`s type by calling the ShowDialog overload which accepts an`IWin32Window` overload and passing the currently executing form.  Typically Me.

```
BMSSplash.MyBuddy.ShowDialog(Me)
```

I don't have much experience with splash screen implementations though and it may have a slightly different API.

Comment: Oh no I just have my splash screen doing all the work up front.

Answer (score 0):

p.s.  If you want to do .showDialog with a "splash" screen, you can add a timer on that form and have it me.dispose when the timer fires.